# Flutter -How to create checkbox with image and text?

Tags: flutter, dart, checkbox

How to create a CheckboxListTile with an image in the container and text?

All of the above should be in a row. I tried, but I get a blank screen. How to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Sample code:

```
CheckboxListTile(
                            title: Image.asset('images/image_1.png'),
                            secondary: Text(
                              'lorem ipsum hby hweby fhr',
                              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                  color: Color(0xff000000),
                                  fontSize: 15,
                                  letterSpacing: 0.4),
                            ),
                            value: _isChecked,
                            onChanged: (bool? newValue) {
                              setState(() {
                                _isChecked = newValue ?? false;
                              });
                            },
                            activeColor: Color(0xff82b235),
                            controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                          ),
```

Comment: this code looks good, have you tried to wrap this in a sizedbox or container with fixed height and width?

Comment: please add full widget code :)

Answer (score 0):

**add below scrip in pubspec.yaml**

assets:

- assets/images/image_1.png

  ```
  bool _isChecked = false;

     @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        return Scaffold(
          body:  Container(
                      child: CheckboxListTile(
                        title: const Text('Title'),
                        subtitle: const Text('subtitle'),
                         secondary: Image.asset('images/image_1.png'),
                        value: _isChecked,
                        onChanged: (bool value) {
                          setState(() {
                            _isChecked = value;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    )
  ```

  ,
  );
  }